# Visually impaired mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to integrate a mode for visually impaired people in my website, like in https://www.actionforblindpeople.org.uk/other-pages/accessibility-statement-and-options/

I need some examples of scripts that enable that,if it possible some documentations about VI disability.

I would like to suggest to add that option for this website too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could tackle the problem.

**1-** Swap css sheets 
(Where you would have smaller sheets that only target font-sizes and colors)

**2-** Apply a css class to your body.
(Example below)

**3-** Some javascript query.
(see http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/usability/)

It depends on the size of your project and the behaviors you want to implement. For example, clicking the "enhance contrast" button could add a highConstrast class to your document body.

Your css could be something like this:

```
.myDiv{
    background-color:#303030;
    color:#red;
}

.highContrast{
    background-color:white !important;
    color:black !important;
}
```

You can also override the rules individualy if the design requires it.

```
.myDiv.highContrast{
    background-color:yellow !important;
}
```

CSS isn't my forte, feel free to question this method, but it does get the job done.

Comment: Thank you, I found this http://jsfiddle.net/eYgdm/  it's can be coded for VI..